# Controlling variable by character

Tags: c++

I am making calculator in c++ and i have a question. Is there a way to do someting like this?

```
if( x = "+" )    {y = 1}
if( x = "-" )    {y = 2}
if( x = "*" )    {y = 3}
if( x = "/" )    {y = 4}
```

I need to control "y" by using characters "+ - * /" and its giving me errors like "error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|" I dont know what it means

I am beginner. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You're using `=` (assignment) when you mean to use `==` (comparison).

Comment: Your code can be more compact: `x = "/"; y = 4;` (sarcasm)

Comment: And to make a character literal, you put it in SINGLE quotes. DOUBLE quotes are for strings. You really need to go back to your textbook and learn the basics.

Comment: When you have a sequence of mutually exclusive tests, you should use `else if` instead of just `if`.

Answer (score 4):

1. The comparison operator is `==`. `=` is for assignment or initialization.
2. `"+"` is a string literal a.k.a. `char[2]`; `2` because of the null byte. A character is `'+'`. Note that character literals in C++ are `char`s while in C `int`s.
3. Use an `else if` or even better a `switch` control structure. `switch` leaves more room for optimization to the compiler like a jump table or a hash map.
4. This numeric assignment to `y` does not look nice. Use an `enum` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd want to use a `switch` statement, something on this general order:

```
switch (x) {
    case '+': y = 1; break;
    case '-': y = 2; break;
    case '*': y = 3; break;
    case '/': y = 4; break;
}
```

If you had a larger number of possibilities (or might need to load possibilities from an external data file, etc.) you might want to consider using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead:

```
std::map<char, int> ops;

ops['+'] = 1;
ops['-'] = 2;
ops['*'] = 3;
ops['/'] = 4;

y = ops.find(x)->second;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( x == '+' )    {y = 1}
if( x == '-' )    {y = 2}
if( x == '*' )    {y = 3}
if( x == '/' )    {y = 4}
```

x = something mean assing to the variable x the value of something

x == something mean if x contain the same value of something, then return true, else return false.

for char variable, remember to use ' instead of "

Another way to do that is using switch

```
    switch(x){
        case '+':
            y = 1;
            break;
        case '*':
            y = 2;
            break;
etc...
    }
```